java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/JumperData.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
I have issue with writing to external storage. Existention and permission to writing are verified sucssefull. At manifest is inputed permission for writing but command "FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)" throws exception from title. Where is solution?
package com.example.writepermission;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 112;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checkPermission()) {
        writeToFile();
    } else {
        requestPermission();
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
}

private void writeToFile() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "JumperData.txt");
    if(file.exists()) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write("Hello, World!".getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
            Log.d("MyApp", "File written successfully.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        int a = 20;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            writeToFile();
        } else {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Permission denied.");
        }
    }
}

}

I assume you looked at the documentation about how to write files? Unless you are using an old version of android its not as simple as writing to a path. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage
